# Assigning values to players on a team

Tags: algorithms

There are $4$ different teams $(A, B, C, D)$, each with $15$ people. All these teams competed against one and other in a competition. Each person in a team teamed up with another person inside their team for each event of the competition. After the competition, players could see how they placed in the competition ($1$st, $2$nd, $3$rd, or $4$th). I need a way to assign values to each players to find how which people did the best in the competition overall. Each person did a different amount of events.

For example, one person on the $A$ team may have only done $1$ event and placed $1$st, but another person on the $B$ team may have done $3$ events and placed $1$st, $1$st, and $2$nd. This person on the $B$ team would be valued more because they did more events and still placed quite well.

Any help with with would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you need a more formal definition of the score you are looking for. For example if a player in team A wins one time is that better than a player in team B that came 2nd two times?

Being said that, you can for example assign scores with the following expression
$$s_k = \sum_i \dfrac{c_i}{i}$$

Where $c_i$ is the number of times the player $k$ finished in the $i$-th place. In you example the scores would then be
$$c_a = \dfrac{1}{1} = 1$$
$$c_b = \dfrac{2}{1}+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{5}{2}=2.5$$
So $b$ would win.

Notice that with this approach finishing 2nd 2 times is the same as finishing first one time, and so on.

Now, this is not a definite and/or only solution. Maybe this will turn out to be not fair in some cases.

Comment: I probably should have made that clearer in the question, but yes I do need a more formal definition of the score I want. I like the start that you have on this. In which situation(s) do you think that this may be unfair?

Comment: I'm not sure, it depends on the problem, maybe coming second two times is worse that coming first one time. To (partially) solve this you can add a factor, say $\alpha_i$ so the contribution of getting a $i$-th place is $\alpha_i\frac{c_i}{i}$ so if $\alpha_2=0.5$ now finishing 2nd 4 times is the same as finishing first one time.